# In Java, can i extract a single field from a list of objects and assign it to a variable using lambda?

Tags: java, list, lambda

I have a list of DTOs, and i would need to extract a single field from a list of object, but just once. It doesn't matter from which object on the list it's extracted, since the field is valorized with the same value on every object in the list.

For example:

```
List<T> list;
dateDTO Fields:    ID Date        Price
                    1 02/02/2019   33.5
                    2 02/02/2019   15.5
                    3 02/02/2019    7.5
                    4 02/02/2019   30.0

String date = "this would need to be valorized with the field 'Date'";
```

Given that the date field is always the same, how can i achieve this by using lamdba? In the class method i only have access to the list, not the single object.

Edit : Updated my question to reflect the fact that the list is a List, that gets passed various DTOs, but i only need to do this for a single of the possible DTOs i pass, since only that one has the date i need. Lets' call it dateDTO.

Comment: @GhostCat I can't copypaste the actual code since it's a class from work, but i'll try to make a minimal reproducible example and edit my question again. If i can ask, why did you delete your comment under John Kugelman's answer? I thought that part about not using stream() was very useful to know.

Comment: I tend to keep things clean, and only leave things around that are really essential to the question / answer.

Comment: Please create a [mre]. Code is a lot better than a description of it. If you can't show us your actual code that's fine; strip out the unrelated work details. Make up something that demonstrates the problem concisely.

Answer (score 4):

```
Date date = list.isEmpty() ? null : list.get(0).getDate();
```

```
Date date = list.stream().findAny().map(DTO::getDate).orElse(null);
```

```
Optional<Date> date = list.stream().findAny().map(DTO::getDate);
```

Comment: I've tried all three solutions, but i get this error:
error: method map in class Optional<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: @GhostCat you are right, i forgot to add that the list is a List<T> that can take in any object, but it's mostly used for various DTOs. I will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Function<List<DTO>, Date> datePicker = dtoList -> dtoList.isEmpty() ? null : dtoList.get(0).getDate();
```

should do.

In other words: you need to define a function that receives a `List<DTO>` and that returns a a Date object. And you implement by simply taking the first entry (for non-empty lists).